# Installing Stomp on PHP7.0

Tags: homestead, stomp, pecl, php-7

I am having trouble installing Stomp on PHP7.0 via PECL.
It errors out trying to find a PHP5 header file (php_smart_str.h) which is php_smart_string.h in PHP7. Now I see a php7 branch in this [repo](https://github.com/php/pecl-tools-stomp).

Now I am stuck in not knowing how to install Stomp in my Homestead PHP7 box. Who can help me out here?
The repo also doesn't seem to contain the right files for me to run `./configure` or `make (install)`.